# CSS blend effect of 2 div with text

Tags: css

Is it possible to create such an effect in CSS?

[image]

The digits should change dynamically, so it would be great if the HTML structure looked something like this:

```
<div class="digits-show">
    <div class="digits-show__text">enter our world</div>
    <div class="digits-show__bg"> 42342379723094873294872398479347239....2424</div>
<div>
```

I tried to use "mix-blend-mode" CSS property, but without success.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do with web tools with reasonable time and effort. Especially with dynamic content. With static content I would try clip path / SVG, _maybe_

Comment: @vsync that is a solid comment. HAHAH. Temani always comes through. CSS master.

Comment: I can also do it but it will take me an hour+ which I don't have due to work piling up...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible with `mix-blend-mode`, you just have to set your colors differently to start. The overlayed text needs to be `white` and the `mix-blend-mode` should be set to `difference`.

```css
.digits-show {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 700px;
}
.digits-show__text {
  font-size: 7rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 50%;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
}
.digits-show__bg {
  animation: scroll 20s infinite linear;
  color: #dcdcdc;
  transform: translateY(0);
  width: 100%;
  word-break: break-all;
}

@keyframes scroll{
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}

body {
  display: grid;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="digits-show">
  <div class="digits-show__text">enter our world</div>
  <div class="digits-show__bg"> 423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424423423797230948732948723984793472392424
  </div>
  <div>
```

Edit: added an animation for proof of concept.